# Compiling PostgreSQL extension, getting "error: ‘work_mem’ undeclared (first use in this function)"

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-extensions

When I compile the extension I've got, I'm getting

```
error: ‘work_mem’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   17 |   Tuplestorestate *tupstore = tuplestore_begin_heap(true, false, work_mem);
```

What header includes `work_mem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`work_mem` symbol is provided by `misadmin.h`](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/miscadmin_8h.html#accff143c230b4ba995087f712f374c17) you will have to add that header into your `.c` file.

```
#include "miscadmin.h"
```